# Smooch ConversationActivity, how can I know when the activity was launched?

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent, smooch

I have implemented smooch. https://smooch.io/
And my issue is that when I get the notification from smooch. If I'm in the background, I set a "unread messages" long that I use in my main activity on the smooch button.
The issue is that when I press on the notification, and the ConversationActivity is started from there. I need to set the unread messages to 0, because the ConversationActivity is opened. How can I know when this happens?

I cannot modify ConversationActivity.class from the smooch library.
I thought about making the notification myself, and changing the smooch created one with this one using this code:

```
 private static void generateNotificationSmooch(final Context context, String title, String message) {
    if (title == null)
        title = context.getString(R.string.passenger_name);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ConversationActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    int iUniqueId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, iUniqueId, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(title).setContentText(message).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(intent);
    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

But I need to set the unread to 0 when the notification is pressed, and not when I create the notification. And I can't put it in pending intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. Use the [onSmoochShown](https://docs.smooch.io/api/android/io/smooch/core/Conversation.Delegate.html#onSmoochShown--) delegate callback.

   This callback will be triggered when the conversation is shown, so you will be able to update your unread count.
2. Use the [onUnreadCountChanged](https://docs.smooch.io/api/android/io/smooch/core/Conversation.Delegate.html#onUnreadCountChanged-io.smooch.core.Conversation-int-) delegate callback .

   This delegate will be called whenever the unread count changes for current user. You can use this callback to update your long accordingly.

Since you will need to be listening to these delegate callbacks when a notification is tapped, it may be best to set your delegate in your Application’s `onCreate`, after you initialize Smooch.

Comment: Yes this works. implementing the Delegate made it possible